Cached data using Spring
Could you give me please some advices why data cache in the Spring app doesn't work.
My app works with a table RequestHitory in Posgres DB.
I want to cache data from this table in my Spring App.
I use @EnableCaching annotation for the App:
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCaching
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

}

RequestHistory class is
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Table(name="requesthistory")
@Data
public class RequestHistory implements Serializable {

    @Id
    String name;

    @Column(name="request_last_date_time")
    LocalDateTime requestLastDateTime;

}

DAO repository is
@Repository
public interface RequestHistoryDAORepository extends JpaRepository<RequestHistory, String> {

    RequestHistory findByName(String name);
}


I have a service:
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
//@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "requests")
public class RequestHistoryService {

    private final CacheManager cacheManager;

    private final RequestHistoryDAORepository requestHistoryRepository;

    @Cacheable("requests")
    public RequestHistory getRequestHistoryByName(String requestName) {
        return requestHistoryRepository.findByName(requestName);
    }

    public Cache getCacheData() {
        Cache data = cacheManager.getCache("requests");
        return data;
    }

}


I try to research how the data caching works in Spring.
I use the code:
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AllDataLoader {

    private final RequestHistoryService requestHistoryService;

    public void load() {
        requestHistoryService.getCacheData();
        RequestHistory requestHistory = requestHistoryService.getRequestHistoryByName(requestName);
        requestHistoryService.getCacheData();
    }
}

When I run this code, I see that cache doesn't include any data after first invocation of RequestHistory requestHistory = this.getRequestHistoryByName(requestName).
Could you help me please to understand why data cache doesn't work in my case.

This code wouldn't even compile? Does the requestHistoryService.getRequestHistoryByName call even return something? What is your cache implementation in use? You also shouldn't need @EnableCaching just specify spring.cache.type=<your-cache>.

This code works.
requestHistoryService.getRequestHistoryByName(name) returns the data from the table
